# Is it Too Slow to Run Yosemite Under Yosemite using Parallels

Tags: parallels

Got a new MacBook Air. Want to run different configurations of Yosemite (e.g. with and without Dropbox to test its effect on battery life). Is the latest version of Parallels fast enough to run Yosemite under Yosemite, or am I going at this wrong?

Comment: Why not just install and uninstall dropbox?

Comment: If you're going to test battery life, doing it through virtualization is the completely wrong thing to do as it adds cup load just to virtualized.

Comment: I did "just install and uninstall dropbox" as one of many, many other experiments I've been running. It did not seem to be the culprit. I do understand virtualizing will affect battery life. Thought was to run baseline tests with Parallels on.

A second consideration for using parallels is that I just want the ability to use and throw away different configurations rapidly. I think that's one of the selling points of virtualization, or am I wrong?